# Calling method of container object from component object Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have two classes in Python:

```
class Component(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False

    def compnent_method(self):
        if self.flag:
            # Call a method, called_from_component, from the container
```

and

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.component = Component()

    def container_method(self):
        self.component.component_method()

    def called_from_component(self):
        # Do some stuff. This is the method I want self.component to call
```

Calling `container_method` from container will call `component_method` from the component object. Depending on the values of `component.flag`, I would like to call, from the component object a method that resides in the container, `called_from_component` .

How can I do this in Python 2.7?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do here, to be honest. Can't you just check `component.flag` inside Container, rather than the other way round? And is the method you want to call dynamic, or is it always `called_from_component`?

Comment: It's always called called_from_component. This is part of a larger project. Due to separation of concerns, I perform a certain type of operations in Component. Container is only responsible with communicating the results. I cant called_from_component to act like a callback basically.

Comment: I am not a Python programmer. But your design seems wrong to me. A component should not know anything about container, if it is a composition relationship. You may be looking for inheritance rather than composition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to pass the container instance into the `component_method`:

```
class Component(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False

    def component_method(self, container):
        if self.flag:
            # Call a method, called_from_component, from the container
            container.called_from_component()

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.component = Component()

    def container_method(self):
        self.component.component_method(self) ## <--- Here

    def called_from_component(self):
        # Do some stuff. This is the method I want self.component to call
```

Another way to do this is to pass the `Container` instance into `Component`'s constructor:

```
class Component(object):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.flag = True
        self.container = container

    def component_method(self):
        if self.flag:
            # Call a method, called_from_component, from the container
            self.container.called_from_component()

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.component = Component(self)  ## <---- Here

    def container_method(self):
        self.component.component_method()

    def called_from_component(self):
        # Do some stuff. This is the method I want self.component to call
        print 'Called from component'
```